# Does PHP reinitialize session variables when visiting a page in another tab?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

I am building a simple website in PHP 8.0.30 where after the user logs in successfully, specific values are added to the `$_SESSION`, including their last time of access as follows:

**index.php**

```
<?php
  # Code below is simplified to focus on the relevant lines
  if ($userisauthenticated) {  
    $_SESSION['lastaccess'] = time();
    echo "<script>console.log('Code in index.php was run'); </script>"; 
  }
?>
```

If the user loads another page again in the future, I check the last time of access and if that is within a specified time limit, load the rest of the page or otherwise log them out. See below for an example:

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo "<script>console.log('lastaccess: " . $_SESSION['lastaccess'] . "' ); </script>"; 

  # The code afterwards tries to check if the user is still logged in
  if (array_key_exists('lastaccess', $_SESSION)) {
    if (time() - $_SESSION["lastaccess"] < 60 * 60 * 48) {
      # Go ahead and load page
    } else {
      # Log user out
    } 
  }
?>
```

However, I am running into a strange issue where if I log in via `index.php`, then minutes later open a new tab and visit `dashboard.php` by directly typing the url, the `lastaccess` value is different from what `index.php` had set it. The first two lines literally are what I have above, so there is no code before it to change the `lastaccess` value.

I also inserted a test output to the console in `index.php` to see if the new tab is for some reason pre-loading `index.php`, but that test output is never printed to the console when I load `dashboard.php` in a new tab.

This also only happens some times I try this (not always), which makes me wonder if it has anything to do with my browser (I am using Google Chrome).

Is it possible that PHP reinitializes the value stored in the `$_SESSION` variables on page load in a new tab? What am I missing in my knowledge of PHP sessions here and what is causing this?

Comment: PHP doesn’t know anything about tabs client side. PHP receives HTTP requests and responds to them, that’s all.

Comment: Sessions are associated with a session cookie, by default named `PHPSESSID`. As long as both tabs send the same cookie (which they generally do), they'll be in the same session.

Comment: You can check the cookies in Developer Tools to see if they're the same in both tabs.

Comment: just make sure that every page that is intended to maintain and use sessions starts with `session_start();` - the above `index.php` does not appear to do so

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is the pre-fetching setting in Google Chrome. When I type out the URL, the first suggestion is the main URL, which points to `index.php`. Google Chrome is prefetching the page which is triggering the script (my fault for not having set it up right).

Figured this out when I opened a new tab just to type the URL, did **not** go to that page and closed the tab instead, then went back to my test page that I had set up to see the `lastaccess` value, refreshed it, and saw that the value had been updated!

Answer (score 0):

**Summary Answer:**

NO!

**Detailed Answer:**

Each time `$_SESSION` is accessed, `session_start()` command must be executed. Before reading and even writing a value in `$_SESSION`.

Therefore, it is necessary to execute the `session_start()` command in the `index.php` file before using `$_SESSION`.

​
new **index.php** :

```php
<?php
  session_start(); // <--- will fix next access
  # Code below is simplified to focus on the relevant lines
  if ($userisauthenticated) {  
    $_SESSION['lastaccess'] = time();
    echo "<script>console.log('Code in index.php was run'); </script>"; 
  }
?>
```